Does LSALOGONUSER works with certificate encoded hash in username field with password empty or not?
Below shared code works for normal username, password scenario. But a discussion in this question (How to do certifcate login in windows without the use of smart card by using LSALOGONUSER?) came to a conclusion that in place of username , certificate encoded hash could be used. Is it possible to do so? I tested it but wasn't able to succeed. I used a smart card logon template certificate for this .
    #include <ntsecapi.h>
    #include <ntstatus.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <winnt.h>

    #pragma comment(lib, "Secur32.lib")

    // Function Prototypes
    size_t wcsByteLen(const wchar_t* str);
    void InitUnicodeString(UNICODE_STRING& str, const wchar_t* value, BYTE* buffer,
                           size_t& offset);

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
      // connect to the LSA
      HANDLE lsa;
      LsaConnectUntrusted(&lsa);

      /*const wchar_t* domain = L".";
      const wchar_t* user = L"hp";
      const wchar_t* password = L"Prabhat8954@";*/
      const wchar_t* domain = L"test.com";
      const wchar_t* user = L"CERTIFICATE_ENCODED_HASH";
      const wchar_t* password = L"";

      // prepare the authentication info
      ULONG authInfoSize = sizeof(KERB_INTERACTIVE_LOGON) + wcsByteLen(domain) +
                           wcsByteLen(user) + wcsByteLen(password);
      BYTE* authInfoBuf = new BYTE[authInfoSize];
      KERB_INTERACTIVE_LOGON* authInfo = (KERB_INTERACTIVE_LOGON*)authInfoBuf;
      authInfo->MessageType = KerbInteractiveLogon;
      size_t offset = sizeof(KERB_INTERACTIVE_LOGON);
      InitUnicodeString(authInfo->LogonDomainName, domain, authInfoBuf, offset);
      InitUnicodeString(authInfo->UserName, user, authInfoBuf, offset);
      InitUnicodeString(authInfo->Password, password, authInfoBuf, offset);

      // find the Kerberos security package
      char packageNameRaw[] = MICROSOFT_KERBEROS_NAME_A;
      LSA_STRING packageName;
      packageName.Buffer = packageNameRaw;
      packageName.Length = packageName.MaximumLength =
          (USHORT)strlen(packageName.Buffer);
      ULONG packageId;
      LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage(lsa, &packageName, &packageId);

      // create a dummy origin and token source
      LSA_STRING origin = {};
      origin.Buffer = _strdup("TestAppFoo");
      origin.Length = (USHORT)strlen(origin.Buffer);
      origin.MaximumLength = origin.Length;
      TOKEN_SOURCE source = {};
      strcpy_s(source.SourceName, "foobar");
      AllocateLocallyUniqueId(&source.SourceIdentifier);

      void* profileBuffer;
      DWORD profileBufLen;
      LUID luid;
      HANDLE token;
      QUOTA_LIMITS qlimits;
      NTSTATUS subStatus;
      NTSTATUS status = LsaLogonUser(
          lsa, &origin, Interactive, packageId, authInfo, authInfoSize, 0, &source,
          &profileBuffer, &profileBufLen, &luid, &token, &qlimits, &subStatus);
      if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        ULONG err = LsaNtStatusToWinError(status);
        printf("LsaLogonUser failed: %x\n", status);
        return 1;
      } else {
        printf("LsaLogonUser success: %x\n", status);
      }
    }

    size_t wcsByteLen(const wchar_t* str) { return wcslen(str) * sizeof(wchar_t); }

    void InitUnicodeString(UNICODE_STRING& str, const wchar_t* value, BYTE* buffer,
                           size_t& offset) {
      size_t size = wcsByteLen(value);
      str.Length = str.MaximumLength = (USHORT)size;
      str.Buffer = (PWSTR)(buffer + offset);
      memcpy(str.Buffer, value, size);
      offset += size;
    }

